# Refresh location after visibility change

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to refresh an html page when a div becomes visible... Not sure where I am going wrong. The divslide.js switches the display style from none to inline at set times. I want the div with the id final to refresh the page so that it loops back through each div.

Here is the html...

```
<div id="video" class="mySlides"><video autoplay><source src="icx.mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="widescreen" class="mySlides">
<!--<div id="written"><video autoplay><source src="written.mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>-->
</div>

<div id="final" class="mySlides"></div>
```

I have linked jquery 3.1.1 and am trying to use ...

```
if($('#final').is(':visible'))
{
location.reload();
}
```

seems pretty basic, but it is not working.

Comment: Why refresh the page, post your js for the looping please, refreshing the page is nuts, just restart the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of restarting the slides is... well... nuts.

Without your js for that part here's basically what you want to do.

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="video"><video id="video1"><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

CSS

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#div4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

jQuery

```
// Create an array of the video divs.
var videos = [
  "div1",
  "div2",
  "div3",
  "div4"
]
var videos = [
  ["div1", 4000],
  ["div2", 6000],
  ["div3", 11000],
  ["div4", 5900],
]

// Initate a counter at 1 because you're going to show the first video by default.
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    // Hide all the video divs
    $(".video").hide();
  // Show the video div based on the counter
  $("#" + videos[counter][0]).show();
  // Reset the video to the beginning
  $("#video" + [counter]).load();
  // Play the video
  $("#video" + [counter]).play();

  //Increment the counter if there are still more divs to show, otherwise reset it to 0
  counter == videos.length-1 ? counter = 0 : counter++;
}, videos[counter][1]);
```

JSFiddle showing it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/nky4n2cx/

Comment: Thank you for this... It is definitely a better approach. However, how do I get it to display the video in its entirety instead of using 3000? Also, I am trying to get the videos to restart rather than loop. This is why I was trying to refresh the page. I don't want the videos to be in the middle of playing when they become visible, I want them to run from the beginning.

Comment: I edited the code in my answer to show how to make the interval variable too, you just need to know the length of each video in ms, then add that to the array. I've also added how to start and play the videos from the beginning when the slide changes using a basic HTML5 video element. Should work, I don't know of any free video streaming services to test it though.

Comment: Thanks again... The array is working now in the sense that it is looping through each based on the set time. But now it is not recognizing the index when I try to load the video.

Comment: Sorry was away for a few days, not sure what you mean by recognizing the index?

Comment: Thanks.. I found a solution. I appreciate your assistance.